# giving margin to a fluid div shows horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Yes now i've got the grid outertcontainer fixed but somehow its not expanding 100%.
Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.
i am giving the emitted css.
**if you see it in full screen you can see the outer container div is still not 100%.**
Thanks.

Here is the 
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uegtmykb/)
      * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box; }

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

img {
  max-width: 100%; }

.bordered {
  border: 1px solid black; }

.redbordered {
  border: 1px solid red; }

.greenbordered {
  border: 1px solid green; }

.outerContainer {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 133px;
  background-color: crimson; }
  .outerContainer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; }
  .outerContainer .leftSide {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 200px; }
    .outerContainer .leftSide:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }

.leftNav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 133px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px; }
```

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/o3jxrve7/

Answer (score 0):

Of course, position:fixed is exactly for that purpose, to have the element fixed in that position, overlapping everything below it. To have a regular 2 columns layout with no overlapping, just try this (there are many ways to do it, this is just one using CSS without changing your HTML)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    min-height:100%;
}
.leftNav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: black;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.rightContainer {
    background-color:silver;
    min-height: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.fluid {
    width: 89%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/nd8Ldprv/)

remove width 100% in **fluid**  and make **rightContainer**  as width **auto** and **margin-left 100px**

```
.rightContainer
{
background-color:silver;
min-height: 300px;
width:auto;
margin-left:100px;
}
```